# Why not let users pay for bounties?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Here is my crazy idea of the day:

The bounty feature is great to get better answers or to solve tricky problems.
New Drupal users won't have the skills (or time and patience) to contribute enough on this site to make use of bounties.

If they could pay for bounties we might get more activity and excitement going on this site. For example, if someone needs some custom feature/code developed he/she could pay $5 for a 50 point bounty, for example.

The money could be donated, for example to the Drupal Association. The success of Fiverr.com shows that there is plenty of need for getting tasks done for a few bucks.

Edit:
I changed the title and question to better reflect my intend. The goal isn't to mess with the reputation system but provide a feature to get high quality answers to anyone in need.

Answer (score 3):

Bounties are a privilege for those who have earned the community's trust. Letting people buy bounties and use them in the same manner as people who earned them legitimately is contrary to how Stack Exchange sites work.

Comment: I have a different point of view here. I see bounties as a challenge to earn points. If I know the person asking the question even better but it could be someone unknown. I wish there would be more bounties offered and more challenging problems to solve. Currently there are only one to two 50 bounties a week. I think it would be fun to solve 100, 200 or even 500 point bounties. The solutions coming out of this would benefit the our community here.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed feature is still "messing" with the reputation because the bounty is given to the user who posted the answer in the form of reputation.

Also with the actual system, the bounty is given as reputation to a user, but the difference is that now there is a user who loses reputation, and a user who gets reputation from the bounty (if the conditions for getting the bounty are met). With feature proposed here, there would be users who could gain 500 points for a single answer simply for the fact a single user assign them a bounty, which would be something every users could be do easily, and more frequently. (I am assuming that the money required to buy a bounty would not be too high, in this proposal; differently, if the price of a 100 point bounty were $1000, there would be few users who buy a bounty.)

Making bounty more easy to be offered would have the opposite effect. If there is a question with a bounty, then it is probable that somebody focuses on answering that question for getting the bounty; if the questions with a bounty are much more, users would not have a reason to answer your question, because they could answer any other question with a bounty. It is like saying that the purpose of the bounty will be diminished.

Your request seems to be going in the opposite direction of what recently changed in the way bounties work.
Suppose that I offer a bounty for a question for which I posted an answer; I could offer a bounty of 50. After I assigned the bounty to an answer, I can offer another bounty (there can be just a bounty active for each question), but this time I am forced to offer a bounty of at least 100 (the double of my previous), and if I offer a bounty of 100, the next time I need to offer a bounty (for the same question) of at least 200.
This has been done because they noticed that some users offered a bounty of 50 for a question they answered, with the effect to get their answer up-voted (because the question got more attention, and with it also the answers given to that question); at the end, even with the offered bounty, they gained reputation. (Gaining 50 points with up-votes on an answer is not too difficult: 6 up-votes give you already 60 points.) With the proposal suggested here it could be easier for somebody to put a bounty, and then gaining reputation with the answer already given before the bounty.

Comment: yeah, I hear your concerns. Doesn't look like anyone else is liking the idea but I thought I present it anyway. I still do see a market need for "pay for answers" in the Drupal world. Fiverr.com is very popular and I do get awesome work done there. However the solutions are not made public. Thanks again for everyone's feedback!

Comment: You should also consider that privileges are linked to reputation. It seems bad, to me, to make them depend from the payment done from somebody.